# Avoiding null exception in EF that is thrown by your query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

I have a query like this :

```
        result =
            firstIdeaRepository.FindBy(
                i => i.FirstIdeaState == FirstIdeaState && i.Date >= start && i.Date <= end)
                               .AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(j => new RptListOfCompanyBasedOnFirstIdeaState()
                                   {
                                       Name =
                                           companyRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == j.UserId)
                                                            .FirstOrDefault()
                                       DateOfMeeting =
                                           calenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(
                                               meetingReposiotry.FindBy(s => s.FirstIdeaId == j.Id)
                                                                .FirstOrDefault()
                                                                .Date),
                                       DateOfExit =
                                           calenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(j.DateOfExit.Value),
                                       ReasonOfExit = j.ReasonOfExit,
                                   }).ToList();

    return result;
```

As you can see i use `FirstOrDefault()` and `j.DateOfExit.Value` and sometimes my Date doesn't have any values or sometime my other variables are null too because i use `firstordefaut()` like

```
companyRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == j.UserId).FirstOrDefault().
```

So my query throws a null exception and the result can't be created ,how can i handle this exception and for example if the .NET detects the null value ignores it by default or uses a default values for that ?

Best regards.

Comment: where i can set a first or default value ?

Comment: You would use `.DefaultIfEmpty()` in the call-chain before `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @martin_costello: `.DefaultIfEmpty()` won't help for reference types, the default for which is null.

Comment: Where exactly are the `NullReferenceExceptions` being thrown?

Comment: meetingReposiotry.FindBy(s => s.FirstIdeaId == j.Id) and date.value

Comment: @Mrchief Use the default value overload. See my answer.

Comment: Getting a NullReferenceException indicates that part of the query is being executed in memory. Is this query intended to be fully executed in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the following changes:

```
result =
    firstIdeaRepository.FindBy(
        i => i.FirstIdeaState == FirstIdeaState && i.Date >= start && i.Date <= end)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(j => new RptListOfCompanyBasedOnFirstIdeaState()
            {
                Name =
                    companyRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == j.UserId)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
                DateOfMeeting =
                    callenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(
                        meetingReposiotry.FindBy(s => s.FirstIdeaId == j.Id)
                            // project a new sequence first, before calling `FirstOrDefault`:
                            .Select(s => s.Date)
                            .FirstOrDefault(),
                DateOfExit =
                    j.DateOfExit.HasValue ? 
                        callenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(j.DateOfExit.Value) :
                        null,                       
                   ReasonOfExit = j.ReasonOfExit,
               }).ToList();
```

When you use `FirstOrDefault`, there's a possibility that you'll get `null` back (in the case of reference types), and so you need to plan for that in your code.

For example, when assigning `DateOfMeeting`, you could project the results (using `.Select`) before using `.FirstOrDefault`, so that you're not ever accessing the `Date` property on what could be a null value.

As for `DateOfExit`, I've used the conditional operator to determine whether to call the `calendarRepository`'s method at all. This assumes that `DateOfExit` is nullable.

*Unrelated*: "Calendar" is spelled with one "l" and not two.

Comment: Thank you dear i change it from two to one thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a nullable date, you can try filtering by values that have date, something like:

```
.FindBy(s => s.FirstIdeaId == j.Id && s.Date.HasValue)
```

This will ensure that you don't get any records with null date.

As I mentioned in comments, other cases need to be handled on case-by-case basis. Judging by the code you've shown, maybe you can handle `Name` as:

```
 Name = companyRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == j.UserId).FirstOrDefault() ?? "anonymous";
```

and so on.

Another example:

If you do want to get the record even if `DateOfMeeting` is null, then add a check for `HasValue` in subsequent part or default it to some date:

```
 DateOfExit = j.DateOfExit.HasValue ? 
              callenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(j.DateOfExit.Value)
              : (DateTime)null,   // you need to make `DateOfExit` nullable and then handle that downstream

// or (default with current date)
 DateOfExit = j.DateOfExit.HasValue ?
              callenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(j.DateOfExit.Value) 
              : callenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(DateTime.Now),

// or (default with empty date)
 DateOfExit = j.DateOfExit.HasValue ?
              callenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(j.DateOfExit.Value) 
              : callenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(new DateTime()),
```

Moral of the story: figure out *what* the default value should be in case of null and then substitute that accordingly in the query when calling `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: So what about other null exception ? like companyRepository.FindBy(i => i.UserId == j.UserId)
                                                            .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: I was going to add that to my answer. So basically the others have to be taken up on a case-by-case basis. you have to decide _how_ you want to handle null values in those cases. E.g., for Name, you substitute it with a default value (empty string or Noname) so that you don't get null reference exceptions when you access them.

Answer (score 0):

The broadest solution would be to use the idea of an [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) with the [DefaultIfEmpty<T>(T DefaultValue)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx) method in your query. An example would be:

```cs
var defaultMeeting = new Meeting() { Date = new DateTime() };

var dateOfMeeting = meetingRepository.FindBy(s => s.FirstIdeaId == j.Id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultMeeting)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Date;
```